# unexpected vertical space when using termcal.sty

Tags: vertical-alignment, calendar, termcal

When creating a Tuesday-Thursday schedule and adjusting the calendar width, such as for two column formatting, there is an unexpected vertical space on Tuesdays. This does not happen with a Monday-Wednesday schedule

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\begin{document}


\begin{calendar}{8/29/2016}{3}

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.5in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{3in} % <----- If this is set to 2in per weekday or above the problem disappears.

\skipday % Monday (no class)
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (school in summer)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday} % Thursday
\skipday % Friday (no class)
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)


\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled Minimal Working Example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tell the truth about the first day of class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{8/30/2016}{3}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.5in}%
\setlength{\calwidth}{3in}% <----- If this is set to 2in per weekday or above the problem disappears.
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}% Tuesday
\skipday % Wednesday (school in summer)
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}% Thursday
\skipday % Friday (no class)
\skipday\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

[image: tidied timetable]